# How to install android studio?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

I have used the following command to install android studio to Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

However, the following message appears :

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

What is the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely run what the apt-get output says:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

It should solve your problem. This command configures all packages that has been unpacked but not configured yet. See:

`man dpkg`

for more details.

Comment: what `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do ?

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your comment.